# Generalization of two methods

Tags: c++, templates, refactoring

Consider the structure:

```
struct B {int b1, b2;};

struct A {
  std::set<B, compBLess> m_setLess;
  std::set<B, compBGreater> m_setGreater;

  void onFirst(int val) {
    auto i_set = m_setLess.begin();
    auto comp = [&](){ return val >= i_set->b1; };

    while ( i_set != m_setLess.end() && comp() ) {
      sameForBoth(*i_set);
      ++i_set;
    }
  }

  void onSecond(int val) {
    auto i_set = m_setGreater.begin();
    auto comp = [&](){ return val <= i_set->b1; };

    while ( i_set != m_setGreater.end() && comp() ) {
      sameForBoth(*i_set);
      ++i_set;
    }
  }

  void sameForBoth() {}
};
```

Is it possible to refactor methods `onFirst` and `onSecond` into one laconic without suffering code maintanability? Note, that `compBLess`/`compBGreater` can't be used instead of `comp`.

My take on the problem:

```
  template<typename TSet>
  void onBoth(int val){
    TSet* set;
    if ( std::is_same<TSet, decltype(m_setLess)>::value ) {
      set = reinterpret_cast<TSet*>(&m_setLess);
    } else {
      set = reinterpret_cast<TSet*>(&m_setGreater);
    }

    auto i_set = set->begin();

    std::function<bool()> comp;
    if( std::is_same<TSet, decltype(m_setLess)>::value )
      comp = std::function<bool()>([&]() { return val >= i_set->b1; });
    else
      comp = std::function<bool()>([&]() { return val <= i_set->b1; });

    while ( i_set != set->end() && comp() ) {
      sameForBoth(*i_set);
      ++i_set;
    }
  }
```

But my solution seems too complex. Also I'm not sure that using `reinterpret_cast<>` in such manner is a good practice.

Is there any other way?

Comment: It "seems too complex" because both methods are very small, and short, to start with. Any attempt to combine them together will likely result in one large function or template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both functions, we are iterating over a range, from the beginning of the `std::set` up-to a given iterator which depends on the input value.

In this answer, I'll assume that `compBLess` and `compBGreater` are defined like this (the important part is that the b1 field is predominant over b2. And see at the end for a slightly different version)

```
struct compBLess {
  bool operator ()(B const & o1, B const& o2) const {
      return std::make_pair(o1.b1,o1.b2) < std::make_pair(o2.b1,o2.b2);
  }
};
struct compBGreater {
  bool operator ()(B const & o1, B const& o2) const {
      return std::make_pair(o1.b1,o1.b2) > std::make_pair(o2.b1,o2.b2);
  }
};
```

Under this assumption, then I think the idiomatic way to do this is to use [lowerbound, upperbound methods of std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to find the end of the iteration , and then use

```
template<typename Iterator>
void foo(Iterator it, Iterator end) {
    std::for_each(it,end,[this](auto & o){ sameForBoth(o); });
}
```

This will be performance-wise more efficient, because we will do O(log(size_of_set)) comparisons (using lowerbound / upperbound) instead of O(size_of_set) comparisons (using `comp` in the loop)

The actual implementation of the other methods looks like this:

```
void onFirst(int val) {
    foo(m_setLess.begin(), m_setLess.lowerbound({val,std::numeric_limits<int>::min}));
}
void onSecond(int val) {
    foo(m_setGreater.begin(), m_setGreater.upperbound({val-1,std::numeric_limits<int>::max}));
}
```

Edit: Following @z3dd's comment, Here is the implementation that works for slightly different `compBLess` and `compBGreater` (the ordering vs. the `b2` field is reversed):

```
struct compBLess {
  bool operator ()(B const & o1, B const& o2) const {
      return std::make_pair(o1.b1,-o1.b2) < std::make_pair(o2.b1,-o2.b2);
  }
};
struct compBGreater {
  bool operator ()(B const & o1, B const& o2) const {
      return std::make_pair(o1.b1,-o1.b2) > std::make_pair(o2.b1,-o2.b2);
  }
};

void onFirst(int val) {
    foo(m_setLess.begin(), m_setLess.lowerbound({val,std::numeric_limits<int>::max}));
}
void onSecond(int val) {
    foo(m_setGreater.begin(), m_setGreater.upperbound({val-1,std::numeric_limits<int>::min}));
}
```

[Note that if `compBLess` and `compBGreater` are not implemented like any of the 2 implementations given, then the answer of @Ilio Catallo is the one to use.]

Comment: Missing closing brace and paren in first code example

Comment: @iMajuscule the functors are slightly diff-t, i.e. for compBGreater it's: `o1.b1 > o2.b1 || (o1.b1==o2.b1 && o1.b2 < o2.b2)`

Comment: @z3dd I edited my answer to include the code that should work for you.

Comment: @z3dd note that the comparison operators for std::pair first compare the first field, then the second, this is why it works!

Comment: @iMajuscule That's a neat trick with pairs! I'm taking it. Regarding foo(): I feel like looking for a lower_bound is unnecessary. Since set is sorted and I need all values before some threshold, I can start with `begin()` and increment until I reach the TH, neither skipping nor missing anything.

Comment: @z3dd You can do that of course, but as I explained in the body of the answer, you have a linear complexity when doing it this way, instead of the logarithmic complexity that upper_bound / lower_bound will give you. But maybe in your particular case you don't need to be fast...

Comment: Although it is true that you do `logn` (where `n` denotes the size of the range) comparisons for carrying out the bisecting approach in `set::upper_bound` (and `set::lower_bound`), you still need at most `n` increments for executing `std::for_each`. However, you can avoid paying the `logn` part if you directly apply the action to each element until the predicate holds. That is,  at most `n` predicate applications are needed to execute `apply_until`

Comment: @IlioCatallo Yes, the number of iteration doesn't change, but the cost per iteration is slightly lower with my solution.

Comment: My argument is that carrying out a bisection (`upper_bound` / `lower_bound`) followed by a loop (`for_each`) costs `O(n + logn)`, whereas directly applying a function  element-by-element until some predicate holds costs `O(n)`.

Comment: @IlioCatallo well, O(n + logn) is equal to O(n), which is also equal to O(n+n), I don't see your point. I'm taking about optimizing the constant : Yes, in both cases the algorithm is linear but the constant is different because in one case, for n iterations we do n comparisons, and n operations, in the other case we do log n comparisons and n operations.

Comment: You are right in terms of Big-O notation. The rationale behind my comment is that you always need exactly `logn` comparisons to execute the bisecting algorithm behind `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`; but since you are going to visit the elements (a fraction of `n`) for which the predicate holds in any case, my attitude was to avoid this fixed cost all along.

Comment: @IlioCatallo You're wrong : on average, (let's assume we are traversing half the set on average), your approach needs to do exactly n/2 comparisons, while mine needs approximately log n comparisons. When you say "a fraction of n" you assume that we will traverse a very little part of the set at each iteration, but I don't see why this would be the case.

Comment: @iMajuscule In the average case, I need n/2 predicate applications. You need logn predicate applications, regardless the case. Which means that as long as n is less than 16, the linear approach is to be preferred.

Comment: Actually, it's rather "if n is less than 4, then the linear approach is better" because when n > 4, n/2 > log n

Comment: So.. unless a tiny set of 0,1,2 or 3 elements is used, then the bisecting approach will be better, on average, and not taking memory locality into account  :)

Comment: @iMajuscule Yes, you are right :) A possible advantage I see of `apply_until` is that it is a single-pass algorithm, i.e., it can work with `InputIterator`s

Comment: Every approach has it's advantages and inconvenients, I can agree with that :)

Comment: Seems that I'm late for the party. @iMajuscule I understand that it's a trade between one time O(logn) vs O(1) for each iteration, however, taking into consideration the data structure access pattern IRL, it seems to me that using `lower_bound` would be superior for my problem, thus I'm marking your solution as the answer.

Comment: @z3dd Thanks. In all fairness, I would say that if the cost of what's inside 'sameForBoth' is much bigger than the cost of the comparison then the 2 approaches are similar performance-wise.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this correctly, it seems that you want to apply an action on each element that happens to satisfy the `comp` unary predicate. Therefore, we may scan the elements linearly and apply a function until a given predicate holds.

Since you are working on a range, a possible approach is to design a generic procedure, as in:

```
template <typename I, typename P, typename F>
// I models InputIterator
// P models UnaryPredicate
// F models UnaryFunction
// Domain<P> == ValueType<I>
// Domain<F> == ValueType<I>
void apply_until(I first, I last, P p, F f) {
  while (first != last) {
    if (!p(*first)) return;
    f(*first);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

We can use such a generic algorithm to, e.g., print out the values in a range that happen to be strictly less than `3`:

```
int main() {
  std::set<int> s1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  apply_until(s1.begin(), s1.end(), [](int x) { return x < 3;}, [](int x) { std::cout << x << '\n'; });
}
```

I would keep the distinction between `onFirst` and `onSecond`, as they are meant to operate on distinct sets. The code for your use case may reduce to something like:

```
void onFirst(int val) {
    apply_until(m_setLess.begin(), m_setLess.end(), [&](B const& x) { return x.b1 >= val; }, [&](B const& x) { sameForBoth(x); });
}

void onSecond(int val) {
    apply_until(m_setGreater.begin(), m_setGreater.end(), [&](B const& x) { return x.b1 <= val; }, [&](B const& x) { sameForBoth(x); });
}
```

Comment: There are other procedures after the `while` loop that I omitted, but they can be moved past `apply_until()` and the overall solution looks reasonable, thanks!

Comment: I'm glad you found it helpful!

Comment: There is a typo in 'onSecond', b2 should be replaced by b1 (I can't do the edit myself because an edit must change at least 6 characters...)